# How to use expressions inside ng-click and ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a expandable rows to the table.  I do not get any error messages but it is not working as expected. I suspect there is something wrong how I am using expressions with ng-show here? 
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DVVCsXxrhDQaACTAa2rj?p=preview)

my code:

```
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>itemOne</th>
        <th>itemTwo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="data in tableData| orderBy:'-clintonValuemain'">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button ng-show="data.expand" ng-click='data.expand = true'>+</button>
          <button ng-show="!data.expand" ng-click='data.expand = false'>-</button>
          <input type="checkbox" class='checkbox'>
          <a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href={{data.url}}>
        {{data.name}}
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{data.valueMain}}</td>
        <td>{{data.tValue}}</td>
        <tr>
          <tr ng-show="data.expand" ng-repeat="subs in data.subvalues| orderBy:'-clintonValuesub'" >
            <td>
              {{subs.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{subs.valueSub}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{subs.tValue}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tr>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

```
<button ng-show="data.expand" ng-click='data.expand = false'>-</button>
<button ng-show="!data.expand" ng-click='data.expand = true'>+</button>
```

updated plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/sJDFAp1KDvhYh8K3q7z2?p=preview